# Hiding an image within a window.open screen using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe that holds a page. Now on that page, I have an image link that allows the user to detach the same screen from within the iframe and open into a new window using window.open(url,'newWin').

My questions is, as I am opening the same window that has the image link into a another screen using window.open(url,'newWin'), the same image link appears.

Any ideas how I could go about hiding this image within the window.open window alone using jQuery. The image is within a div id="img_link"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you didn't try my original answer. Here is an updated solution that should work for you:

```
$(function(){
    var img = $("#img_link");
    if(window.name == "newWin"){
        img.hide();
    } else {
       img.click(function(){
          window.open(window.location, 'newWin');
       });
    }
});
```

Since you are loading the same page twice, the code tests if it has been given a window name. If it has, it knows its the sub window and hides the link. If not, it attaches the click event which opens the popup window.

Comment: Hi Doug, at the moment, I am using the following call:

    $(document).ready(function(){ 

      $('div#img_link').click( function(){
              window.open(window.location ,'newWin','scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, status=no, resizable=yes');
        });

    }); 

How would I incorporate your function call above?

Thanks.